# Is there a name for the use of sunlight in metabolic processes?

Tags: physiology, metabolism, terminology

"Photosynthesis" is what is used to describe how plants use sunlight to synthesize sugars, but, I also heard some animals like humans use sunlight in the process of creating vitamin D. Is there a comparable name for when sunlight is used by animals in a metabolic process?

Comment: Perhaps you would want to replace "animals" with "organisms". I don't think there would be a special term just for animals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Photometabolism** or **photocatalysis** would be apt terms and the former would specifically refer to biochemical reactions.

**Photometabolism** is also used in the context of the light dependent conversion of 7-dehydrocholesterol to Vitamin-D.

A [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=photometabolism&btnG=) with **photometabolism** returns many peer-reviewed articles that have used this term. Some examples:

1. [Photometabolism of 7-dehydrocholesterol to previtamin D3 in skin.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/194588)
2. [The photometabolism of glucose by an hydrogen-adapted alga](https://doi.org/10.1016/0006-3002(61)90173-1)
3. [Photometabolism of Heterocyclic Aromatic Compounds by Rhodopseudomonas palustris OU 11.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16349307)

Comment: "photo-metabolism" also, e.g.[here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13398198).